# Determine if the integral converges $\intop_{1}^{2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I want to determine if the following integral converges

$$\intop_{1}^{2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}dx$$

My intuition tells me it diverges. I thought the way to solve that woudln't be by definition but by finding another function that is smaller than that and use integral comparison test. I also know that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\log=0$$ but I don't see how that helps me

Comment: L'Hopital says $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin x}{\log x} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\cos x}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to 1} x \cos x = \cos 1$

Comment: why can i use L'Hopital $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\sin\left(x\right)\thickapprox0.84$$

Comment: I don't think you can use l'Hopital's rule here.

Comment: @user75453 You're absolutely right. I was thinking $\sin 1 = 0$. Must have just woken up when I typed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $logx \leq x-1$. So $\frac{sinx}{lnx} \geq \frac{sin1}{x-1}$ for $x \in (1,2]$, and $\intop_{1}^{2}\frac{\sin\left(1\right)}{x-1}$ diverges. So $\intop_{1}^{2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}$ divergent.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to check that for $x\to 1$, we have
$$\frac{\sin x}{\ln x}\sim \frac{c}{x-1},$$
where $c=\sin(1)$.

Hence, your integral converges iff.
$$\int_1^2\frac{c}{x-1}\mathrm d x=c\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\mathrm d x$$
converges.

Does it?

Comment: Why can L'Hopital be used? The form of the limit is $\sin(1)/0$, which isn't a use case for L'Hopital if I remember correctly.

Comment: I gave an alternative answer. Sorry for the original mistake.

Comment: Where $ c=sin(1) $ not $ x=...$

Answer (score 0):

$f:  x\mapsto \frac{\sin(x)}{\ln(x)} $ is continuous at $ (1,\frac{\pi}{2} ]$ and positive.

in the other hand,

$$\ln(x)=\ln(1+(x-1))$$
thus
$$f(x)\sim \frac{\sin(1)}{x-1} \;\;\;(x\to 1^+)$$

and

$$\int_1^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{x-1}$$
is divergent. So, your integral is Divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $e^x \ge 1+x$ for $x\in(-1, \infty)$. This means that $\log(1+x) \le x$ for $x\in(-1,\infty)$. Hence, $\log(x)\le x-1$ and $1/\log x \ge (x-1)^{-1} $ for $x\in(0, \infty)$. Now, you know that $|\sin x/\log(x)| \ge |\sin(x)|/(x-1)$ on $[1,2]$. The norm of your integral is thus bounded below by
$$\int_1^2\frac{|\sin x|}{x-1}\,dx,$$
which diverges because of the singularity at $x=1$. Conclusion: your integral also diverges.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\sin x}{\log x}>\frac1{2\log x}\quad\forall x\in(1,2]$$ and as such, by finding that $$\int_1^2\frac1{2\log x}\,dx=\frac12\left(\text{Li}(2)-\text{Li}(1)\right)$$ is divergent, we can conclude that $$\int_1^2\frac{\sin x}{\log x}\,dx$$ is divergent as well.